# calculating the distance of a frustum that intersects a point on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d

My problem revolves around trying to position a camera in 3d space.

The points **O** and **Q** exist on a flat plane, the point **P** exists along a vector **M** which passes through **O**. What is the position of **P** such that **Q** intersects with any of the four planes of a pyramid shaped frustum with four sides with its peak centred on **P** and directed at **O** so that **O** is contained within the pyramid with $\theta$ denoting the angle between opposing sides of the pyramid, in other words the top corner angle of any side of the pyramid is $\theta$.

[image: diagram of frustum]

Comment: This question is not well-posed.  Please review it and add more details.  Which plane of the frustum do you mean?  How do you define the field of view ?  And what exactly is $\theta $ here ?

Comment: @Calmdownandhavesometea Is that more clear now? It's easier to see by looking at the diagram and a little tricky for me to describe in only words. Maybe another way to look at it would be starting at **O** a point **P** rises along a path **M** until a pyramid it casts down intersects with **Q**.